# Print original format of Java Process Inputstream

Tags: java, process, inputstream

Just wondering if it is possible to keep the original format of the console messages redirected from an external Jar through java process inputstream.

I am invoking an external Jar tool and printing out its messages on the console.
This is the code I use for it:

```
proc = rt.exec(java -jar External jar with arguments);
String line;
BufferedReader inMsg = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
while ((line = inMsg.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
in.close();
```

However, this external Jar program implements a progress bar to show file download process, which essentially updates the same line as:

```
private static void printProgBar(double bytesCopied) {
    double percentDone = ((bytesCopied)/(curretnFileSize));
    percentDone *= 100;
    StringBuilder bar = new StringBuilder("[");

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if (i < (percentDone / 2)) {
            bar.append("=");
        } else if (i == (percentDone / 2)) {
            bar.append(">");
        } else {
            bar.append(" ");
        }
    }

    bar.append("]   ").append(df.format(percentDone)).append("%     ");
    if(percentDone > 1){
        System.out.print("\r" + bar.toString());
    }
}
```

Output is something like this:

```
[=======                                           ]   12.51%
```

Okay so when I redirect this through inputstream, it prints each change in the percentage on the new line. I want to respect the original  format. Any suggestions, how can it be possible.

Comment: Can you modify that printProgBar code?

Comment: @Pablo: Yes that could be done as well. But without changing the functionality. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are using `println` to write while the original output is written using `print`. `\r` makes the cursor go to the beginning of the current line, but println make it one forward.

I'd try to use `print` instead of `println`. You could check if the line starts with a `\r` character and if no, then add a new line after that.

Comment: yeah good point. However checking \r didn't work. But checking  [ or ] worked. Still its a dirty hack. I need to make my both  the jar applications more generic. :-)